# How to make link on a whole <li> that has border image?

Tags: html, css, menu, hyperlink, navigation

I would like some valid code, no `<a><li></li></a>`
Here is the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/BquwS/

I have to add the code here too, because i can't ask jsfiddle-link-only questions, so this is the html:

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the css i have problem with.

```
#menu {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:15px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu li{
    height:15px;
    background-color:#404468;
    margin:20px 0 20px 0;
    /*border-image*/
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-image:url("http://users.atw.hu/darksoul90/egyeb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 stretch stretch;
    border-width:17px 17px 17px 17px;
    -moz-border-image:url("http://users.atw.hu/darksoul90/egyeb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("http://users.atw.hu/darksoul90/egyeb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 stretch stretch;
    border-image-outset: 10px;
}
#menu li:nth-child(odd){

    -ms-transform:rotate(1deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
    transform:rotate(1deg);
}
#menu li:nth-child(even){
    -ms-transform:rotate(-1deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
    transform:rotate(-1deg);
}
#menu a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    color:#b7c4d8;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color:#Ff0;
}
```

Comment: Please add actual code to your question, rather than just a link to jsfiddle. You can see the meta discussion regarding the problems with jsfiddle-link-only questions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I's funny, because everybody asks for the jsfiddle version :) I added the code here too.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the thick borders the clickable zone of the link is narrow. You could expand the clickable zone of the link but that would require absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/89Rv8/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/89Rv8/7/show

```
#menu li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu a {
  color: #B7C4D8;
  display: block;
  left: -17px;
  line-height: 30px;
  min-height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: -17px;
  width: 141px;
}
```

Comment: Could it be a problem in any browser?

Comment: Not the AP technique but border-image. http://caniuse.com/border-image (only IE11 not IE 10 - IE 9 ...)

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

you should erase the "#" on the href. If # is on your href, if you click it it stays on the page and nothing happens.. Change it to the correct link you want to if you click the buttons.

Comment: The original code is <li><a href=\"?m_id={$row['m_id']}\">{$row['m_nev']}</a></li> the link itself works, but i want the whole <li> to act like a link.